# Pass screen with parameters in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm using the `screen` option in the `navigate` function in order to navigate to a specific screen in the `Home` stack, as below :

```
navigation.navigate({name: 'Home', screen: 'Rate', item: this.state.id})
```

The problem I have is that the `item` parameters is not passed to the `Rate` component.

How can I pass parameters to the final component when using `navigate` this way ?

Comment: Try this way `navigation.navigate({name: 'Home', screen: 'Rate', {item: this.state.id}})`

Comment: This is not valid JS syntax, is it ?